# Flutter:Error: Getter not found: 'suspending'. case AppLifecycleState.suspending

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to use plugin camera_camera. But when I try compile project I get this error:

Flutter: Error: Getter not found: 'suspending'. case AppLifecycleState.suspending.

I read that this is problem cause by update version native_device_orientation plugin but owner this plugin don't resolved this.

How can I resolve this problem alone?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a way to edit the auther's code.. you can't really.